# Exclude zoom level in leaflet stamen map

Tags: javascript, leaflet, zooming, stamen-maps

I have got a very basic `stamen map`. If I zoom to level 19, the map is not shown. 
I think this is because of the max level 18 in the the file http://maps.stamen.com/js/tile.stamen.js.
What can I do, to provide someone to zoom to level 19?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Eine OSM Karte mit Leaflet</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.1.0/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.1.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.stamen.com/js/tile.stamen.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="height: 700px;" id="mapid"></div>
<script>
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([50.27264, 7.26469], 13);
var layer = new L.StamenTileLayer("watercolor");
mymap.addLayer(layer);
</script>
  toner,terrain,terrain-classic,watercolor
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it is possible to override the options of the `StamenTileLayer`.

After it is instantiated, simply set its `options.maxZoom` (to 19 in your case, so that the layer remains on map at that zoom level) and `options.maxNativeZoom` (to 18 in your case, so that Leaflet does not try to fetch tiles at zoom 19 but instead re-uses those from zoom 18 and scales them appropriately).

```js
var layer = new L.StamenTileLayer("watercolor");

// Override Tile Layer maxZoom.
layer.options.maxZoom = 19;

// But specify that tiles are available only up to zoom level 18.
layer.options.maxNativeZoom = 18;
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/gumgWckQycEvg9Gaqt3s?p=preview

Comment: Nice, did not know this one.